# LNK2019 error when building MySQL codei n VIsual Studio C++

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, mysql-connector

I've spent about two days now trying to get this to work but I still keep getting the same error with every method I do. I'm new to connecting MySQL to C++ so I'm a bit lost and every time I try to compile it, the thing spits out LNK2019 error. I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>
using namespace std;

// DATABASE STUFF
struct connection_details {
    const char* server, * user, * password, * database;
};

MYSQL* mysql_connection_setup(struct connection_details mysql_details) {
    MYSQL* connection = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (!(mysql_real_connect(connection, mysql_details.server, mysql_details.user, mysql_details.password, mysql_details.database, 0, NULL, 0))) {
        cout << "Connection Error: " << mysql_error(connection) << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return connection;
}

MYSQL_RES* mysql_execute_query(MYSQL* connection, const char* sql_query) {
    if (mysql_query(connection, sql_query)) {
        cout << "MYSQL Query Error: " << mysql_error(connection) << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return mysql_use_result(connection);
}

// MAIN FUNCTION
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    MYSQL* con;
    MYSQL_RES* res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    struct connection_details mysql_db;
    mysql_db.server = "localhost";
    mysql_db.user = "root";
    mysql_db.password = "tAblE4wTe3";
    mysql_db.database = "test";

    con = mysql_connection_setup(mysql_db);
    res = mysql_execute_query(con, "select * from table1");

    cout << "Displaying Database:\n" << endl;

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
        cout << row[0] << " | " << row[1] << " | " << row[2] << endl;
    }

    mysql_free_result(res);
    mysql_close(con);

    return 0;
}
```

Errors it shows:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_error referenced in function "struct MYSQL * __cdecl mysql_connection_setup(struct connection_details)" (?mysql_connection_setup@@YAPEAUMYSQL@@Uconnection_details@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_init referenced in function "struct MYSQL * __cdecl mysql_connection_setup(struct connection_details)" (?mysql_connection_setup@@YAPEAUMYSQL@@Uconnection_details@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_real_connect referenced in function "struct MYSQL * __cdecl mysql_connection_setup(struct connection_details)" (?mysql_connection_setup@@YAPEAUMYSQL@@Uconnection_details@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_query referenced in function "struct MYSQL_RES * __cdecl mysql_execute_query(struct MYSQL *,char const *)" (?mysql_execute_query@@YAPEAUMYSQL_RES@@PEAUMYSQL@@PEBD@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_use_result referenced in function "struct MYSQL_RES * __cdecl mysql_execute_query(struct MYSQL *,char const *)" (?mysql_execute_query@@YAPEAUMYSQL_RES@@PEAUMYSQL@@PEBD@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_free_result referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_fetch_row referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mysql_close referenced in function main
1>C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\C++ Projects\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "Test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

These are the include/library folder locations:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\mysql stuff\libbinlogevents
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\mysql stuff\libbinlogstandalone
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\mysql stuff\libchangestreams
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\mysql stuff\libmysql
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\mysql stuff\libservices
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\vs14

C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\mysql stuff\include
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include
```

I've tried looking it up, and every forum, video, etc. that I try using to resolve doesn't work. I'm not sure if it's a 32-bit or 64-bit issue, though I don't think it is since all files point to 64-bit folders. I'm thinking it's something in my code but I'm very new to this so I can't really pinpoint it. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I managed to solve it, just started the project from scratch and followed the visual studio [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/connect-cpp) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_W4zt5sR1M) video.

Comment: Do you link all the necessary libraries (LIB-files)? What have you added to your _Linker → Input → Additional Dependencies_ settings?

Comment: @heapunderrun I put `mysqlcppconn-static.lib`. This was from a youtube vid btw, but didn't fix a thing.

Comment: Did you install the correct library for each configuration you are using. There likely will be a different `.lib` file for Debug and Release.

Comment: ***I'm not sure if it's a 32-bit or 64-bit issue*** Your linker will tell you if this is the case. You will get a  can not open `filename.lib` error message in the log if the lib is corrupt, not in the place you told it to look or you are mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Maybe it should be `mysqlcppconn8-static.lib`?

Comment: @drescherjm I used the installer for mysql and I got more files from this repo: (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server) but it didn't come with `.lib` files afaik. The connector from MySQL came with the lib files.

Comment: Did you follow the [official notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-notes.html)?

Comment: @heapunderrun didn't work either.

Comment: **Did you follow the official notes** I'll check it right now.

Comment: @heapunderrun that also didn't work. I'm thinking of just doing a clean install of mysql again at this point lol